# Image Editor/Pixelator Not Working, No Idea Why Python 3.5 PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am very new to python, and I have been playing around with image editing using the PIL thing. I came up with a code that is supposed to take an image, and break it into 5x10 pixel blocks, and replace each with the average rgb values for that block I tried to do this by increasing x, y by 10,5 respectively, recording the rgb values for each pixel, averaging them, and allocating them to all the pixels in the block.
However, for all my code, the picture is not changing whatsoever.
I HAVE NO IDEA WHY????
Heres the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def Edit(iar):
    balanceAr = []
    newAR = iar
    global x
    global y
    x = 1
    y = 1

    for eachRow in newAR[::5]:
        Pixx = Pix
        x1 = x
        del x
        x = x1

        y1 = y
        del y


        vr1 = Pixx[x1,y1]
        vr2 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 1]
        vr3 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 2]
        vr4 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 3]
        vr5 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 4]


        yValRAv = int((vr1[0] + vr2[0] + vr3[0] + vr4[0] + vr5[0])/5)
        yValGAv = int((vr1[1] + vr2[1] + vr3[1] + vr4[1] + vr5[1])/5)
        yValBAv = int((vr1[2] + vr2[2] + vr3[2] + vr4[2] + vr5[2])/5)


        for eachPix in eachRow:
            x = 1
            y = 1
            Pixx = Pix
            x1 = x
            del x

            y1 = y
            del y
            y = y1
            vr1 = Pixx[x1,y1]
            vr2 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 1]
            vr3 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 2]
            vr4 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 3]
            vr5 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 4]
            vr6 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 5]
            vr7 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 6]
            vr8 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 7]
            vr9 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 8]
            vr10 = Pixx[x1,y1 + 9]


            xValRAv = int((vr1[0] + vr2[0] + vr3[0] + vr4[0] + vr5[0] + vr6[0] + vr7[0] + vr8[0] + vr9[0] + vr10[0])/10)
            xValGAv = int((vr1[1] + vr2[1] + vr3[1] + vr4[1] + vr5[1] + vr6[0] + vr7[0] + vr8[0] + vr9[0] + vr10[0])/10)
            xValBAv = int((vr1[2] + vr2[2] + vr3[2] + vr4[2] + vr5[2] + vr6[0] + vr7[0] + vr8[0] + vr9[0] + vr10[0])/10)
            ValRAv = int((xValRAv + yValRAv)/2)
            ValGAv = int((xValGAv + yValGAv)/2)
            ValBAv = int((xValBAv + yValBAv)/2) 
            for count in range(5):
                for counter in range(10):
                    Pixx = Pix
                    Pixx[(x1 + counter), (y1 + count)] = (ValRAv, ValGAv, ValBAv)
            x = x1 + 10
        y = y1 + 5
        return newAR
    iar = newAR




i = Image.open('speaker8.png')
iar = np.array(i)
width, height = i.size
Pix = i.load()
Edit(iar)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((8,6), (0,0), rowspan=20, colspan=15)

ax1.imshow(iar)
plt.show()
```

Please note that much of this code has been pieced together from exerts of tutorials, so may not be used in the correct way?

Thanks!

Comment: 1/ You never assign to `newAR`, 2/ you return inside a loop, not at the end of a function, 3/ you assign `iar = newAR` *after* the return statement, so that'll never happen, 4/ you rely on altering a list in a function, instead of returning the altered version, 5/ too many global variables (implicit like `Pix` and needless like `x` and `y`) 6/ you assign width and height to the *size* of the image, which is width*height etc etc. There are too many weird things going on: perhaps you need to step back and learn to program properly in Python first, or find someone to guide you through that.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate your ideas